# How can I maximize the area of a rectangular base and semicircular top when perimeter is not given

Tags: calculus

[image]

I know that the perimeter would be $(2x+y)+\pi r=P$

I am confused in these kinds of optimization problems, which variable to solve for.

I know that area is $xy+\frac{\pi r^2}{2}$

If I solve for r, I get $r = \frac{P-(2x+y)}{\pi}$

Then $A = xy+ \frac{\pi (\frac{P-(2x+y)}{\pi})^{2}}{2}$

Am I supposed to take the derivative now? I am very confused any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: $P = 2xr+\pi r  = 2x+r(1+\pi)$

$A = xr +\frac{\pi r^2}{2}$

$x = \frac{P-r(1+\pi)}{x}$

$A =  \frac{P-r(1+\pi)}{x} r + \frac{\pi r^2}{2}$

$A = \frac{P-r^2+2\pi r^2}{2}$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88841/discussion-on-question-by-user8358234-how-can-i-maximize-the-area-of-a-rectangul).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P=2x+y+\pi r=2x+2r+\pi r$ because the horizontal dimension of the rectangle is equal in length to the diameter of the semi-circle.$$A=xy+\pi r^2/2=2rx+\pi r^2/2$$

Substitute $2x$ from the first equation: $2x=P-2r-\pi r$, to get$$A(r)=r[P-(2+\pi)r]+\pi r^2/2$$Differentiate with respect to $r$ and equate to $0$, giving$$A'(r)=P-2(2+\pi)r+\pi r=0\implies r=\frac P{4+\pi}$$Ensure that this is the value of $r$ that gives the maximum area, then use the first equation to get the corresponding $x$. You could have expressed the area as a function of $x$ by substituting for $r$ too, and then differentiated with respect to $x$ to land at the same answer.

Comment: thank you! when i figured out what you were saying with y = 2r i got the same answer. so now i plug in $P/4+\pi$ into the original equation and i got $x = 4+3 \pi + 1/2 \pi^2 $ is this correct? this value is not in terms of P though

Comment: @user8358234 Check again. $x$ should be in terms of $P$. Using $2x=P-(2+\pi)r$, I'm getting $r=x=\dfrac P{4+\pi}$

Comment: ah sorry i made another mistake. I should get $\frac{1}{P} \frac{4+\pi}{2+\pi}$

Comment: @user8358234 You can't get $P$ in the denominator. It is dimensionally incorrect